# Submit WebSocket request with Nested Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, websocket

Below I have this WebSocket Request;

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "command": "submit",
  "tx_json" : {
      "TransactionType" : "TrustSet",
      "Account" : "r████████████████████████████",
      "Amount" : {
         "currency" : "FLX",
         "value" : "100000000",
         "issuer" : "r████████████████████████████"
      }
   },
   "secret" : "s████████████████████████████",
   "offline": false,
   "fee_mult_max": 1000
}
```

What I have below is a PHP WebSocket Request;

What I am struggling with is you see how `tx_json` in the above example is like an Array.

How would I replicate this in the below Example ; Also `Amount` is an Array within an Array.

Then also values like `Secret` which is outside of the Array.

Thankyou for any help.

```
<?php
    $server = 'xrpl.ws';
    $submitTransaction = json_encode(array(
        'id' => 2,
        'command' => "submit",
        
?????
        
    ));
    
    if( $sp = websocket_open($server, 443,'',$errstr, 10,true) ) {
      websocket_write($sp,$submitTransaction);
      $result = websocket_read($sp,$errstr);
    }else {
      echo "Failed to connect to server\n";
      echo "Server responed with: $errstr\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: tx_json could be represented as an associative array in PHP (just the same as the array you've already started defining). Then "amount" would be another associative array within that. "Secret" is another property of the array you've already started.

Comment: P.s. you could simply run json_encode on the existing JSON and it would give you a valid PHP structure to work with. Ensure you set the second parameter to get an object or associative array as per your preference (see the PHP docs for details). You could then use var_export to print out usable details to paste as hard-coded data in your current PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert example json to array and send it:

```php
$json = '{
  "id": 2,
  "command": "submit",
  "tx_json" : {
      "TransactionType" : "TrustSet",
      "Account" : "r████████████████████████████",
      "Amount" : {
         "currency" : "FLX",
         "value" : "100000000",
         "issuer" : "r████████████████████████████"
      }
   },
   "secret" : "s████████████████████████████",
   "offline": false,
   "fee_mult_max": 1000
}';
$jsonAsArray = json_decode($json, true);
// arrayAsVariable
var_export($jsonAsArray);
```